# Capable as in “having power and ability”?

Tags: translation, word-choice, nuances

> India is a nuclear-capable country.

インドは核**保有**国です。
=having/has/possesses

> He is a capable person.

彼は**有能な**人です。
=an able x

> He is capable of piloting a plane.

彼は飛行機を操縦**することができます**。
=has ability of x

—-

Is there a solid word, written or spoken, to mean capable as in “having power *and* ability”?

—-

For example, a retired pilot (ability) is not capable of flying a plane because they have no power to do so; Canada supplies the world with enriched uranium and has centrifuge facilities (power), but does not have the expertise to go further (ability); A person with intelligence and family money (ability) who engages exclusively in vice after vice is not a capable person (power over oneself).

Comment: Is there a word that meets those conditions in English, or any other language you know?

Comment: Capable, clearly  (It’s one of various dictionary definitions, from MW, too.)

Comment: Isn’t a retired pilot capable of flying an airplane still unable to do so if his/her license is expired?

Comment: Do you have any words in Japanese to offer?

Comment: I wanted to know what would be an equivalent in English or any other language. If “capable” meets your criteria, 能力がある might as well. Even 飛行機を操縦する能力があるパイロット may be prohibited from flying an airplane under certain circumstances.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I messaged some native speakers; this is a tough one. できる, 有能な, 可能な, and 能力 have their unique nuances (even though 能力 looks kind of like ‘skillset/talent’ fused with ‘power’, which is what one of the definitions of *capable* is.)

Given the examples, I’m told 可能な is the most versatile choice closest to *capable*.

However, here is what I reverse-engineered from Google Translate as an experiment that a few Japanese who have been in North America for a while find okay (as a new word, but makes sense to them). Good enough unless there is a better word or loan-word out there.

[image: capable]

例) 彼はケーパブルな人です。

Pulling on this thread just a bit more…

[image: tom]

Some may see how 有能な makes sense naturally and grammatically, but… “has talent/skillset” for something you cannot practice yet you can only do correctly once? English’s *capable* works fine here. (Not to mention the mess with “Tom would make an *unwitting*, capable s—— bomber.”)

—-

**Update**: I’m accepting my own answer because it is not lost in the weeds of picking apart examples and the only answer that tries to capture the concept. Native Japanese in Japan say “there isn’t a single word for capable”, and Japanese who have lived in northern North America for some time say ケーパブル is fine as a loan word because they recognize the nuance. Asked and answered.

Comment: That's good research, but FWIW Tom's bomber now sounds like it's equipped with AI (not auto flight or auto land, but serious Terminator-level stuff). Another point to consider is an example of Bombardier's C-Series - a **technically able** and **authorized with power** (from Transport Canada), definitely capable as an aircraft nevertheless couldn't operate due to political and financial reasons. Now the question "was it capable?" becomes a subjective one and totally depends on the criteria.

Comment: Thank you for the response! About Bomber Tom, check out the movie Arlington Road which exactly fits the example (no AI though) with just clever, manipulative humans .

Answer (score 2):

I think the closest and most neutral equivalent of “capable” is 能力がある. It is usually modified by something that comes before it as in 飛行機を操縦する能力があるパイロット and 核兵器を保有する能力がある国. There may be circumstances where 飛行機を操縦する能力があるパイロット cannot fly a plane, and 核兵器を保有する能力がある国 might choose not to possess nuclear weapons. I think the same can be said about a pilot capable of flying a plane and a country capable of possessing nuclear weapons.

The unmodified 能力がある, and 有能な, are usually reserved for people. 能力のある人 or 有能な人 might use their abilities for evil or waste them completely either by choice or circumstance. I am not sure if the same can be said about a capable person. I would guess so.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no, there is no single Japanese word or phrase that precisely corresponds to the English word "capable" in the range of contexts you have included in your question. In part, this is simply because English and Japanese are two very different languages; naturally, there are many words in each that do not have precise, one-to-one equivalents in the other.

Beyond that, however, I have to say that the definition of "capable" that you have posited in your question seems arbitrary and idiosyncratic,* and is fatally undermined by a putative distinction between "power" and "ability" that doesn't bear much scrutiny. (For example, you have characterized intelligence and family money as an "ability" and engaging in "vice after vice" as evidence of a lack of "power." Couldn't one just as easily say that intelligence and money are forms of "power," while engaging in vice after vice betrays a lack of "ability" to control oneself?) In other words, I'm not at all sure that the word "capable," as you understand it and have attempted to define it, really exists even in English!

---

*[Merriam-Webster's entry for "capable"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/capable) includes six definitions, none of which specifies that being "capable" requires two separate attributes comparable to your "power *and* ability."

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Had you stayed with the first paragraph, it would have been an accepted answer. I’d prefer you intuit “capable” rather than explain in harsh detail how my definition is fatally flawed, however.

Comment: @Drakes, I'm very sorry that second paragraph seemed harsh to you. That certainly wasn't my intention, but I did feel my answer would be incomplete if I failed to point out that your question is premised on a definition of "capable" that isn't commonly accepted. (For what it's worth, my background is in a field in which the candid exchange of views is seen as helpful, rather than impolite. Perhaps that has left me less diplomatic than I ought to be in a forum like this one. I'll try to do better in the future!)

Answer (score 0):

You may assess this by checking if a reasonable excuse/justification can be added or not.

- A retired pilot **has ability** but... can't fly because of license expiration (reasonable excuse)
- A certified pilot **has power** but... but can't fly because of diarrhea (reasonable excuse)

---

The convenient word **できる** may be used as ability, power, competency, etc (or include all of them)., but also accepts excuses/justifications due to its vague nature. We've all heard of such phrase:

- "(**本当は**)できる けれど、 **実際**は ○○のため できない"
- "できる（**能力を有する**） けれど、 ○○のため できない"
- "できる（**立場にある**） けれど、 ○○のため できない"

Thus you might want to accept a combination of words such as:

"能力的にも立場・政治的にも遂行することが可能である"

"It is doable in terms of both capability and power/political-situation"

---

I have encountered a word that won't accept any excuse whatsoever - **available**. A provider "available at your command" implies it is competent, capable, authorized, and ready to serve under the current circumstance. There will be no "but..." or "however..." allowed. Note that it's starting to get subjective from here, and the following word may be industry-specific instead of an "official" word:

The degree of "being available" is **可用性**, and is measured between low or high. If one's availability reaches 100%, you have a service provider that is "having power and ability" to satisfy the given requirement.

As long as "可用性が水準を満たしている" (availability satisfies the requirement), it can, shall, and will get the job done as it is already equipped with the capability and authorized with power.

Comment: Thank you, but I’m not looking for a well-thought linguistic analysis of several words. There is a nuance to “capable” absent in “skilled”, “able”, “possible”, and the like that English has. If there isn’t such word, that is perfectly fine.